# antiderivative around inverse trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I'm just learning about antiderivative that resulted some inverse trigonometric functions, since derivative of $ \arccos (x)$ is $-\frac {1} {\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.
I tried put this value back into integral calculator, but I got $- \arcsin (x)$ instead of $ \arccos (x)$. even though $-\arcsin (x) \neq \arccos (x)$ so why this happen? Kow should I fix my understanding?

Comment: Note:  $arccos(x)$ differs from $-arcsin(x)$ by a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\arccos(x) = \frac{\pi }{2}-\arcsin(x)\implies
(\arccos(x))' =-(\arcsin(x))'
$$

[image]

Comment: that was beautiful!

Answer (score 2):

That's because
$$
\arcsin(x)+\arccos(x) = \frac{\pi }{2}
$$
and $\pi/2$ is a constant.

When integrating, always remember that there's a constant $C$ in the result.